# How to preserve indexes on a SAS table when copying it

Tags: indexing, sas

I have a very big dataset with a few indexeson it. I created a copy of this table, but in my new dataset I have not created any index.

My question is, if I load this copy (without index) to a table which is indexed, will everything be kept, or is it neccesary to create the copy again and before create table set up an indexes ?

Thank for you support

Comment: I edited your title to help people with the same problem find the answer.

Comment: What is your load technique: `proc append`? sql `insert`

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell SAS to index the copy too, either at the point of creation/copy, or afterwards using PROC DATASETS.

```
data copy (index=(var1 var2 var3)) ;
  set master_with_indexes ;
run ;
```

```
proc datasets lib=work ;
  modify copy ;
  index create var1 var2 var3 ;
run ;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Copy an indexed dataset with `proc datasets` `copy`-statement.

A `data` step copies just the data, not the index.
The copy statement copies both.

In library `STIINVIN`, I have a table `ADDRESS`. The below code shows it copies the indexes too.

```
proc datasets nolist;
    copy  in=STIINVIN OUT=WORK;
    select ADDRESS;
proc datasets;
run;
```

[image]

*(The first `proc datasets` does the copy. I suppress the output, because it would only show the situation before the copy. The second `proc datasets` shows the result.)*

Answer (score 1):

> My question is, if I load this copy (without index) to tabel which is
> indexed, everything will be keept ?

Indexes reflect the values that are in the dataset.  So appending data to a dataset that has an index defined will update the index to reflect the new data that has been added.